# Time standard followed by Stack Exchange

Tags: support, reputation, site-faq

I just saw my today's reputation points earning on english.stackexchange.com to be 10 and that too voted up 7 hours ago, though it's just 50 min. past mid-night (IST).

What time standard is followed by Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). You can see the current time Stack Exchange uses if hover your user name on the navigation bar on the top.

[image: user information]

Comment: I just learnt why was i not able to earn reputation points as well as how to answer a question. You answer so beautifully and accurately!